# laravel 5 unable to install Payum package

Tags: php, e-commerce, composer-php, laravel-5, payum

I am trying to use Payum laravel package for my ecommerce site, but I am unable to install it, I issue this composer command:

`composer require payum/payum-laravel-package payum/stripe`

And I get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for payum/payum-laravel-package 0.13.* -> satisfiable
 by payum/payum-laravel-package[0.13.0].
    - Can only install one of: payum/core[0.14.0, 0.13.0].
    - payum/stripe 0.14.0 requires payum/core 0.14.* -> satisfiable by payum/cor
e[0.14.0].
    - payum/payum-laravel-package 0.13.0 requires payum/core 0.13.* -> satisfiab
le by payum/core[0.13.0].
    - Installation request for payum/stripe 0.14.* -> satisfiable by payum/strip
e[0.14.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Keep in mind that I need Stripe/Paypal/Authorize.net for my payments.

Comment: looks like the pakages are not made for this version of laravel

Comment: The package payum/payum-laravel-package 0.13.0 does not support Laravel5. The support was added only in 0.14.0 version. Check the requirements: https://packagist.org/packages/payum/payum-laravel-package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)